# Migrating a rails app up to 3.1, having trouble getting sass to behave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I'm migrating a pre-Rails-3.1 app up to 3.1 (actually, someone else did part of the work of attempting to migrate to 3.0; I'd like to go ahead and get it up to 3.1 now).

When I create a new Rails 3.1 app with `rails new`, the skeleton app seems fine.

When I run `rake test` or `thin start` in the migrated app, though, I get:

```
/Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@zmy/gems/sass-rails-3.1.0.rc.6/lib/sass/rails/template_handlers.rb:32:in `<class:SassTemplate>': undefined method `default_mime_type=' for Sass::Rails::SassTemplate:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I *think* I have things configured correctly.  Gems are correct, `application.rb` has:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
```

Is there more that is needed somewhere?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this turned out to be a problem of having too many versions of various gems installed.  The real culprit was the wrong version of tilt, which was being brought in by some other gem.  Clearing that, and resetting Gemfile.lock, took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

May be please try adding one more at application.rb, since rails 3.1 use **scss** as default.

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

and there is some mime related settings at `initializers/mime_types.rb`, so you may try to play with that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also switch to scss if you wanted to, by using the sass-convert command.  I originally used sass syntax, but later decided I liked scss better and switched to that.

```
sass-convert -F sass -T scss mystyle.sass mystyle.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now. My solution was to update the tilt gem as described in this [github issue](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/23). Apparently, the default mime type method, is added after tilt 1.3.0.